# Display user who started a bounty on question in featured tab

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bountied-tab

The "featured" question tab shows a list of the questions with bounties with the user who originally asked the question, and the date it was originally asked.  I am generally much more interested in who modified it to put the bounty on it, and more importantly when the bounty was added.

Could the display be changed to show who modified the question by putting the bounty on, since that seems to be the more pertinent information in it's being in the "featured" queue?

Comment: May be you can explain why this information is more important.  I agree that who asked the question isn't always relevant, but I fail to see why who placed the bounty is more important that it warrants changing the system.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think for the same reason that knowing who asked is the most relevant information in a new (or unanswered) question - some users are more responsible in how they respond to answerers.  Some askers do not accept answers, and some bounty-placers are happy with the attention their question got and see no reason to award the bounty.  When I am looking at a list of bounties, I want to see who placed them.

Answer (score 1):

> that seems to be the more pertinent information in it's being in the "featured" queue

I don't think so (it is my opinion, others opinions may differ). Question is promoted with bounty, and it doesn't matter who started it. The important information is when bounty expires and its amount. If you really want to know when the bounty was started and who started it, see revisions of the question.  You will see who started a bounty and when he was started it.

[image]

Also on the notice the starter of bounty is written.

Comment: I can see that information without going to the revisions.  But I want to see it without opening the question at all.  I don't know why the identity of the original asker becomes an intrinsic part of the question.